# Failed to open DRM device

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg, intel-graphics

When I'm trying to launch anything with optirun, i get an error:

```
keddad@debian:~/ATOM RPG$ optirun ./start.sh
[  161.810701] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19

[  161.810769] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I'm running nouveau drivers, with Intel 630 and GTX 1050 onboard. Here is syslog:

keddad@debian:/$ sudo grep -a bumblebeed /var/log/syslog

```
Dec  3 08:55:27 debian bumblebeed[609]: [   33.537647] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 10:00:20 debian bumblebeed[589]: [   21.118695] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 10:36:13 debian bumblebeed[589]: [ 1980.495073] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 11:26:35 debian bumblebeed[574]: [   19.701795] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 13:00:57 debian bumblebeed[580]: [   19.921079] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 13:05:55 debian bumblebeed[580]: [  317.868146] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 13:06:28 debian bumblebeed[570]: [   19.011365] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 13:08:23 debian bumblebeed[584]: [   19.697084] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 13:18:46 debian bumblebeed[568]: [   20.011287] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 13:21:31 debian bumblebeed[575]: [   18.033479] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 14:45:01 debian bumblebeed[570]: [   20.052553] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 15:08:45 debian bumblebeed[570]: [ 1444.327735] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 15:09:20 debian bumblebeed[586]: [   19.942523] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 15:27:39 debian bumblebeed[588]: [   19.692626] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 15:39:58 debian bumblebeed[588]: [  758.790828] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 15:40:41 debian bumblebeed[603]: [   21.793098] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 18:50:18 debian bumblebeed[603]: [11398.976071] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 18:52:29 debian bumblebeed[25245]: [11530.072241] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 18:55:43 debian bumblebeed[571]: [   20.207146] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 18:58:51 debian bumblebeed[571]: [  207.486380] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 18:59:25 debian bumblebeed[550]: [   21.238599] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 19:00:39 debian bumblebeed[550]: [   94.790957] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 20:41:28 debian bumblebeed[590]: [   20.557528] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.105985] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.106012] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) No devices detected.
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.106021] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.106029] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) no screens found(EE)
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.106037] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.106046] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.106054] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.107116] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Dec  3 20:45:07 debian bumblebeed[590]: [  239.107136] [ERROR]X did not start properly
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250893] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250921] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) No devices detected.
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250931] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250941] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) no screens found(EE)
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250951] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250963] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.250972] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.252243] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Dec  3 21:04:03 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 1375.252262] [ERROR]X did not start properly
Dec  3 21:21:41 debian bumblebeed[590]: [ 2433.439921] [WARN]Received Terminated signal.
Dec  3 21:22:16 debian bumblebeed[591]: [   19.546629] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809499] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809530] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) No devices detected.
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809539] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809547] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) no screens found(EE)
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809555] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809564] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.809572] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.810641] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Dec  3 21:24:38 debian bumblebeed[591]: [  161.810659] [ERROR]X did not start properly
```

And here is Xserver log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[   161.622] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   161.622] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   161.622] Current Operating System: Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64
[   161.622] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root ro quiet
[   161.622] Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
[   161.622] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   161.622] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   161.622]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   161.622] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   161.622] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.8.log", Time: Mon Dec  3 21:24:38 2018
[   161.635] (++) Using config file: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau"
[   161.635] (++) Using config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
[   161.635] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   161.656] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   161.656] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   161.657] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   161.657] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   161.657] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[   161.657] (**) |   |-->Device "DiscreteNvidia"
[   161.657] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   161.657] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
[   161.657] (**) Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
[   161.657] (**) Not automatically adding devices
[   161.657] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   161.657] (**) Not automatically adding GPU devices
[   161.657] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   161.657] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   161.657]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   161.657] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   161.657] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   161.657] (==) |-->Input Device "<default pointer>"
[   161.657] (==) |-->Input Device "<default keyboard>"
[   161.657] (==) The core pointer device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
    Using the default mouse configuration.
[   161.657] (==) The core keyboard device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
    Using the default keyboard configuration.
[   161.657] (II) Loader magic: 0x558d1125be00
[   161.657] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   161.657]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   161.657]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   161.657]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   161.657]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   161.658] (--) using VT number 2

[   161.658] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   161.658] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   161.658] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[   161.660] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1c8d:103c:836b rev 161, Mem @ 0xb3000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   161.660] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   161.660] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   161.661] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   161.661]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   161.661]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   161.661] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[   161.661] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[   161.677] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   161.677]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.13
[   161.677]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   161.677]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   161.677] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
[   161.677] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
[   161.684] (II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   161.684]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.9.2
[   161.684]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   161.684]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   161.684] (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
[   161.685] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module kbd
[   161.685] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[   161.685] (II) Unloading kbd
[   161.685] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
[   161.685] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Sep 20 00:31:06 2016 -0400
[   161.685] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[   161.685]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[   161.685]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[   161.685]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[   161.685]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[   161.685]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[   161.685]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[   161.685]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[   161.685]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[   161.685]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[   161.685]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[   161.686]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[   161.686]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[   161.686]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[   161.809] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
[   161.809] (EE) No devices detected.
[   161.809] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   161.809] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   161.809] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   161.809] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
[   161.809] (EE) 
[   161.809] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

But card is still visible to OS:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b4000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nouveau
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I thought that old drivers might be a problem, but even after updating nouveau from stretch-backports problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix a similar problem by installing nvidia's proprietary driver.
For Debian based operating systems:

```
apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for about a day, it boiled down to the `gdm` user not having the correct permissions.
In my case, I tried to get VirtualGL to work, so all I had to do was add the `gdm` user to the relevant user group:

`sudo adduser gdm vglusers`